# Specification pattern:MultiType Composite Specifications

Tags: domain-driven-design, specifications

I'm the need complex **multi Type** (`<TLeft,TRight>`) specifications Like:

```
public class AndSopecification<TLeft,TRight>
{

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<TLeft> leftSide, ISpecification<TRight> rightSide)
    {
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But all specification examples I see are implemented **single type** (`<T>`) like:

```
public sealed class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T> leftSide, ISpecification<T> rightSide)
    {            
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there any problem if i create complex specifications like:

```
new AndSpecification<Foo,Bar>(new FooSpecification(),new BarSpecification()).SatisfiedBy();
```

So I can reuse all specifications inside each other for different situations then I can have single unique process points which can be composition units of more complex specification trees.

But I cant find an implementation like that.

Am I in a right road?

**Edit:**

I'm translating every conditional sentence which customer uses, into a `specification` and reuse them everywhere the customer reuses the sentence

(In every related `logic`,`query predicate`,`business rule validation` ,..., and I think these `specifications` are naturally the same in each of these situations)

And as the customer do , I create `composite specifications` ,

But I'm accessing them with different infrastructure in each one of situations(`query predicate`,`business rule validation` ,...)

Comment: Are you sure you need it? It's much simpler and effective to encapsulate a specific use case criteria in one object, instead of composing _n_ generic criterias.

Comment: @MikeSW: Why should I rewrite say `IsLogedInUserAdminSpecification` which should be checked per each business logic (and in every `Specification` I define)?

Comment: That check shouldn't be part of your domain, it's part of the infrastructure.

Comment: @MikeSW:would you please explain a bit more? I can't understand.I'm already talking about `AndSpecification<Foo,Bar>` which is part of my infrastructure and I'm reusing it in `IsLogedInUserAdminSpecification` to validate a logical situation (thanks about answering) .

Comment: If we're talking DDD, the specification applies in the Domain, mainly in querying the repository for _Domain purposes_. Checking if a user is admin, is part of the app infrastructure, not part of the Domain. The Domain models business concepts and use cases, it doesn't really care about your users and their rights. That is a concern of the UI and at most of the Application layer, but not the Domain's. An action shouldn't reach the application layer if the client isn't authorized. It's all about Separation of Concerns.

Comment: @MikeSW:Is there any problem if I use `Specifications` to check if `IsLogedInUserAdmin` or `CanCustomerBeDeleted` in my application layer?

Comment: Checking if a user is logged in has nothing to do with a Domain Specification, 'can customer be deleted' is a domain question though. Your app layer should invoke a domain service that encapsulates the rules of customer deletion. However, I wouldn't call it a specification. Rule of thumb: if it's complicated, try to find another way to do it, DDD is a mindset, not a set of rules.

Comment: @MikeSW:Can I use composite specification (which composed from different conditions for different entities) to get complex queries (as DDD is anly a mindset)? oh MikeSW thanks I'm designing an app and needing your guide lines thanks(+1).

Comment: The specifications should have domain semantics, not SQL semantics. The queries (simple or complex) should be encapsulated by a repository, the specification validates some Domain rule. They are different concepts. And your question tells me you are building a CRUD app or at least you're employing a CRUD mindset. You need to 'upgrade' to a higher view of the issue. Think as a designer, modeler not as a programmer. It's not easy if you're used to CRUD, but it gets easier as you practice it.

Comment: @ MikeSW:Just added more info in **Edit** section, thanks Mike.

Answer (score 1):

I have an implementation where I can do the following which enables me to reuse specs as I see fit.

```
public class Composite
{
  public Foo _foo;
  public Bar _bar;
}

var fooSpec = new Specification<Foo>(f => f.IsActive);
var barSpec = new Specification<Bar>(f => f.IsActive);

var comSpec = new Specification<TheComposite>(c => true);

comSpec = comSpec.And(c => c.Foo, fooSpec)
                 .And(c => c.Bar, barSpec);
```

If this is what you are looking for, here is how I did it.

```
public class Specification<TEntity>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> _expression;

    public static Specification<TEntity> Create<TNestedEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TNestedEntity>> propertyExpression, ISpecification<TNestedEntity> spec)
    {
        var replacer = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(spec.EvalExpression.Parameters.First(), propertyExpression.Body);
        var newExpression = replacer.Visit(spec.EvalExpression.Body);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newExpression, propertyExpression.Parameters);
        return new Specification<TEntity>(exp);
    }

    public virtual bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity e)
    {
        return EvalFunc(e);
    }

    public ISpecification<TEntity> And(ISpecification<TEntity> other)
    {
        return new Specification<TEntity>(EvalExpression.And(other.EvalExpression));
    }

    public ISpecification<TEntity> And<TNestedEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TNestedEntity>> property, ISpecification<TNestedEntity> spec)
    { 
        return And(Create(property, spec));
    }
    ...
}

private class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression _replacementExpression;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;

    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression replacementExpression)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _replacementExpression = replacementExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // If the node is the parameter we are trying to replace,
        // return the expression that should replace it.
        return (node == _parameter) ? _replacementExpression : node;
    }
}
```

ExpressionVisitor is part of System.Linq.Expressions

You can of course also implement Or()

I hope this is what you are looking for and this helps.

Comment: Very useful. Why is this the only place on the whole web where I've seen this!? It seems obvious that one should be able to compose a specification from specifications of the main types properties.

Comment: pull request to add this to netfx extensions package...https://github.com/netfx/extensions/pull/3

Answer (score 1):

Creating a specification that does not relate to a specific type of object defeats the purpose. From Eric Evans: "A SPECIFICATION is a predicate that determines if an object does or does not satisfy some criteria." So you always have to evaluate a specification against an instance. Composite specifications are for composing specifications that relate with the same class of objects.

A specification is not the same thing as a business rule. You can have a business rule the uses multiple specifications. Ex: if customer wants to buy a big car then he needs to have some money in his bank account.

```
var bigCar = new Specification<Car>(car => car.Size == "big");
var accountHasMoney = new Specification<Account>(account => account.Balance > 0);

// This rule takes a car and an account
public bool CanBuyBigCar(Car car, Account account) {
  return bigCar.IsSatisfiedBy(car) && accountHasMoney.IsSatisfiedBy(account)
}
```

If you want to re-use those specifications in your sql queries then you can use implicit operators to make it easier to use it with IQueryables:

```
public static implicit operator Expression<Func<T, bool>>(Specification<T> specification)
{
  return specification.Expression;
}

public static implicit operator Func<T, bool>(Specification<T> specification)
{
  return specification.IsSatisfiedBy;
}
```

Now the specification can be queried directly by all IQueryables, IEnumerables and all other sorts of collections.

You can find a ready-to-use implementation here: https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications/tree/master/Nspecifications

Answer (score 1):

I found it a bit confusing to understand why you need to specify over multi-types. But there is no reason why you couldn't do it. Technically speaking you can use a Spec of tuples.

```
var spec = new Spec<(int num, string text)>(x => x.num == 1 && x.text == "a");
```